# How to implement different pallets but maintain the same component overrides with MUI themes?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a react app that uses MUI. We've been developing things within the "light" mode pallet, but would like to add the ability to switch things to a "dark" mode pallet. This change should affect *only* the colors defined within the `pallet` and not any of the other css/styling overrides.

I've done by best to understand the documentation and have looked at several different examples that I've found online, but none seem to show how to do this when your `theme` has more than just `pallet`. And including another `pallet` object gives a warning in the console, but I'm convinced there's a way to do this without reverting to just copying and pasting the `components` and `typography` parts of the theme to the dark version of the theme. Here's our current theme:

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

export const appTheme = createTheme({
  
  palette: {
    mode: "light",

    neutral: {
      main: "#72ccda",
      one: "#ffffff",
      two: "#f5f5f5",
    },

    primary: {
      main: "#72ccda",
      one: "#9edce5",
      two: "#72ccda",
    },

    info: {
      main: "#72ccda",
      one: "#9edce5",
      two: "#72ccda",
    },

  },

  typography: {
    fontFamily:
      '"Ubuntu", "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica",  "Arial", sans-serif',
  },

  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      // "normal" scss styling goes here and will override any MUI stuff
      styleOverrides: `
        .hidden {
          display: none;
          visibility: hidden;
        },

        .json {
          width: 34vw;
          min-wdith: 400px;
          max-width: 800px;
          height: 40vh;
          min-height: 100px;
          max-height: 450px;
          overflow: scroll;
        }
    `,
    },
  },
});


export const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "dark",

    neutral: {
      main: "#72ccda",
      one: "#ffffff",
      two: "#f5f5f5",
    },

    primary: {
      main: "#72ccda",
      one: "#9edce5",
      two: "#72ccda",
    },

    info: {
      main: "#34afc2",
      one: "#9edce5",
      two: "#72ccda",
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily:
      '"Ubuntu", "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica",  "Arial", sans-serif',
  },

 components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      // "normal" scss styling goes here and will override any MUI stuff
      styleOverrides: `
        .hidden {
          display: none;
          visibility: hidden;
        },

        .json {
          width: 34vw;
          min-wdith: 400px;
          max-width: 800px;
          height: 40vh;
          min-height: 100px;
          max-height: 450px;
          overflow: scroll;
        }
    `,
    },
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just make one object with the common parts of the theme? Then each theme can reuse the common part and define it's own palette.

Comment: Ok, yeah I'm just dumb.